# How to count number of files in directory using python

Tags: python

I'm copying a folder of around 70 Gb to another server using robocopy on Windows server.
After that I want to verify that all files were copied.
I don't need to know exactly that they are identical i.e. I don't want to check and compare the size of files BUT my goal just do a 'sanity' type of verification.
I think that if I'll count the number of files in source and destination it would be quite sufficient for my needs.
Note: it should count the number recursively and return me total number.
I tried to use os.listdir() function but it returns a list but I need the total number of files ..
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try [SO] but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

From the advice on the [Return number of files in directory and subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910330/return-number-of-files-in-directory-and-subdirectory) post, I used the below logic to help me resolve my issue.

```
import os
cpt = sum([len(files) for r, d, files in os.walk("G:\CS\PYTHONPROJECTS")])
```